# Proper DocBlock comment for the method of a class, which implements Factory design pattern

Tags: php, oop, autocomplete, phpstorm, phpdoc

**What I mean by *proper DocBlock comment* is a comment which:**

- Conforms to [PHPDoc standard](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc-reference.html)
- Provides [PHPStorm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) autocomplete

**Here is the class itself:**

```php
class Factory_DomainObjects
{
    /**
     * Build domain object
     *
     * @param $name
     *
     * @return M_UserObject|M_TransactionObject
     */
    public function build($name)
    {
        $class = 'M_' . $name . 'Object';
        return new $class();
    }
}
```

It returns one object from `Core_Object` hierarchy depending on `$name` argument.

Currently `Core_Object` hierarchy looks like this:
[image]

I provided [`@return`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/return.html) tag with a `M_UserObject|M_TransactionObject` type description. It provides autocompete for PHPStorm and conforms to PHPdoc standard.

*- But that's exactly what you want, what's the problem?*
*- Yes and no, keep reading :)*

**The problem**:
What if `Core_Object` hierarchy will grow to something like this?
[image]

This will turn `@return` tag description into a mess:

```php
/**
 * @return M_TransactionObject|M_UserObject|M_Foo|M_Foo1|M_Foo2|M_Foo3|M_Bar|M_Bar1|M_Bar2|M_Bar3
 */
```

**The only workaround I found so far: using separate `build` method for each object, ie**

```php
/**
 * Build user domain object
 * 
 * @return M_UserObject
 */
public function buildUser()
{
    return new M_UserObject();
}

/**
 * Build transaction domain object
 * 
 * @return M_TransactionObject
 */
public function buildTransaction()
{
    return new M_TransactionObject();
}
```

What pitfalls you think my workaround has? What would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer here is that you should not be returning multiple object types from a single method. Let me elaborate:

When I say "types", I mean objects that don't all share the same type information in some way. In your case they are all `CoreObject` (which is a **horrific** name by the way). So I would simply label the return type-hint as `CoreObject` and be done with it.

The preferred way of handling something like this though is to use an interface, and have your method return an implementation of that interface. If you don't have a common interface for all return types, then you need to implement different methods (at the least, or possibly different factories).

Comment: `Core_Object` name is a result of my lasyness, it should be `Core_DomainObject`. `Core_object` type-hint wouldn't provide IDE autocomplete. An interface seems to be perfect workaround! Thank you!

Comment: Pedantic note: an interface should never be a *workaround*. It is a contract. It's not meant to type-hint, but to specify behavior and interaction.

Comment: This pedantic note was really worth mentioning. It guided me to Dependency inversion principle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently not possible.

Watch this ticket to see when it will be implemented: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6027

If you do not want to have separate method for each class, then I may only suggest using **PHPDoc @var comments for local variables** (which can be quite inconvenient -- depends on how you are using it):

```
/** @var M_FooObject $myFoo */
$myFoo = $factory->build('Foo');
```

Comment: Thanks for the ticket reference.  
As for the workaround, it makes documentation non-informative (`@return mixed/object` vs `@return M_UserObject`).
Btw, `@var` is [deprecated](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/develop/docs/PSR.md#var). Consider using [`@type`](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/blob/develop/docs/PSR.md#722-type) instead.

Comment: _"Btw, `@var` is deprecated. Consider using `@type` instead"_ -- sure thing -- as soon as it will be actually supported by IDE.

Comment: that *"@var is deprecated"* is a *joke*. They maintainer of that github page should "fix" that, this is wishful thinking and has nothing to do how the docblocks are used. It's too late to change that IMHO.

Comment: @LazyOne `File>Settings>File templates>PHP Field Doc Comment`

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r That "github page" is phpDocumentor official repository. Official repository outdated? Doubt it.

Comment: @an1zhegorodov `..File templates>PHP Field Doc Comment` -- And...? I do not understand what are you trying to say here.

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry, my mistake. At a first glance I thought that altering the template would do the trick. Unfortunately, PHPStorm doesn't recognize `@type` tag, thus there is no type and description detection in when autocomplete shows up.

Comment: @an1zhegorodov _"Unfortunately, PHPStorm doesn't recognize `@type` tag"_ It does now -- available in next public build. In any case: the mentioned **WI-6027** is now fixed, so you can make it work if your factory is done via **static** call: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Answer (score 1):

Suggested way is to first put the general type (if your Factory creates subtypes of a specific type, than this is the type) and then you can add all the subtypes (or the important ones).

This normally works very good with PHPStorm and it is not violating PHPDoc at all.

```
/**
 * @return M_TransactionObject|M_UserObject|M_Foo|M_Foo1|M_Foo2|M_Foo3|M_Bar|M_Bar1|M_Bar2|M_Bar3
 */
```

This is too much. I normally don't have more than three (sub)types with the *@return* tag. I'd say this is a good rule of thumb.

For example:

```
 * @return M_UserObject|M_TransactionObject
```

is okay in my eyes. A comparable hint-move is:

```
 * @return array|string[]
```

or

```
* @return Iterator|string[]
```

The first type signals the defined use (e.g. the last line is `getIterator()` of `IteratorAggregate`), the alternative types are useful to work-around the deficiencies of IDE-Typehinting (PHPStorm never the less is very good with this).

HTH. What @ircmaxell writes is not wrong, however if you leave the first return type for what he means (the interface goes there), you're fine as long as you understand that the alternative types are for the type-hinting only. If a factory method returns many different "types" all those should share one interface. This is important. If you see the long list you had for example, there should be one type and that one type is the interface.

Comment: Why would one factory build objects from different hierarchies? Having separate factory foreach hierarchy sounds more logical and clean to me.

Comment: Hopefully I have not written that, because that was not my intention. Normally a factory should build object from one hierarchy. Hence the base-type, often as interface.